# Creating a subplot after adding plots using for loop

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I have dataframe with an id column. I want to filter the dataframe for a specific id and then add data from columns to a plot (This part is done using a for loop). And finally, I want to add the plots (3 in this case) into a subplot. I have achieved it like this, but the plot I end up with is incorrect. Wondering if anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong (top two subplots are empty, all info seem to be in the third subplot)?

```
function plotAnom(data::DataFrame)
data = copy(data)
uniqIds = unique(data.id)

# Create emplty plots
p1 = plot()
p2 = plot()
p3 = plot()

for id in uniqIds
    # Filter datframe based on id
    df = data[data.id .== id,:]
    p1 = plot!(
        df.time,
        df[:,names(df)[3]],
        label = id,
        line = 3,
        legend = :bottomright,
    )
    p1 = plot!(
        df.time,
        df.pre_month_avg,
        label = id,
        line = 2
    )
    
    p2 = plot!(
        df.time,
        df.diff,
        line = 3
    )
    
    p3 = plot!(
        df.time,
        df.cumulative_diff,
        line = 3
    )
    
    end

p = plot(p1,p2,p3,layout = (3,1), legend = false)
return p
end
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: I don't think you need to `copy(data)` in your function!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you always update the latest created plot, which is your `p3`. When you use `plot!`, you specify which plot gets updated by putting it in `plot!`'s arguments (otherwise it updates the latest one). So I think you should do `plot!(p1, ...)` instead of `p1 = plot!(...)`, and so on.